# Magento Cron Retry on Script Termination

Tags: magento, cron

I'm having an issue with a Magento cron.  I have a method in a Helper Class firing via the cron, but at some points the the method logic, I exit with an error code (ie `error(1)`) if there are issues with files that the method is working with.  It seems that if the method doesn't end normally, Magento cron tries to re-run the script until it hits the 'Missed if Not run In' limit set in the config.

I tried exiting with a success code (ie `exit(0)`), but that doesn't seem to help.  Is there a graceful way to do this so that Magento doesn't try to re-run the script if it errors-out?

Comment: I guess I can answer my own question - wrapping the code in a try-catch and allowing it to exit normally closes out the cron job.  Exiting with a die() or any sort of exit() (even exit(0)) causes Magento to think the job has failed and it will try to run it again.

Comment: Just in case you're not already aware of it: you can answer your own question after passing an 8h limit (comments shouldn't be used for real answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user923990 gave this answer in his own question:

Wrapping the code in a try-catch and allowing it to exit normally closes out the cron job. Exiting with a `die()` or any sort of `exit()` (even `exit(0)`) causes Magento to think the job has failed and it will try to run it again.